# How do you create a public board where members cannot edit, delete or add cards, only admins can?

Tags: trello, trello-organization, permissions

I am creating a list for a non-profit that I want the public/members (volunteers who want to help) to be able to see, vote and comment, but I don't want them to be able to edit/delete cards/add or lists.

How would I go about doing that?

I'm thinking that something like if only admins could use those functions (add/delete/edit) and board/organization members couldn't?

Do I just need to add them to the organization but not the board?

But if I do that will the board still be visible to the public?

You can take a look at the board I am talking about @ http://www.trello.com/offer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only members of the board can edit/delete cards/add or lists. No need to add them to the organization. Your settings should be as follows:

- Visibility: Public
- Voting: Public
- Comments: Public
- Adding Members Permissions: Admins
- Allow organization members to add themselves to this board: Disabled